# Apt / Apt-get / dpkg no longer logging to journald

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian, systemd-journald

I have a systemd service that I install via debian package using the `apt` command on a raspberry pi 4. I've been using `journalctl -xef` to keep track of all log output for debugging purposes while installing the package and running the service.

I'm not sure how I managed this, but at some point today, `apt`'s log output as well as the output of my package's maintainer scripts stopped showing up in the journal. I did have several typos in one of my package's maintainer scripts and I have a tendency to fat finger the keyboard or press the hotkeys sometimes, but I can't find anything in particular that might've caused the issue. It seems that the journal defaults to in-memory storage as well, which is a bummer, because the first thing I tried to fix the issue was a reboot. So now I guess I can't even look back at old journal entries to see if there was something in there that might indicate what had happened.

I also thought perhaps some of the changes I'd made today in the service or package were causing the problem, so I tried installing an older proof-of-concept service/package and that too does not write correctly to the journal.

I've tried to find a way to just reinstall or repair the `apt/apt-get/dpkg` installation, but haven't been very successful. Most questions are related to repairing a package installation *using* `apt`, not repairing the installation of `apt` itself. I also tried to see if there was a way to configure where `apt` writes its logs, but most questions along those lines are related to redirecting `stdout/stderr` when running an `apt` command.

I'm very new to linux and all of the technologies listed above, so I'm not sure how to debug/diagnose this further.

Is there a way to repair/restore the `apt/apt-get/dpkg` installations or configurations on a raspberry pi or is my only option to try to restore to factory defaults or re-install the entire OS?

### Update

Today I learned of the `/var/log` directory. I haven't found any indication within those logs of what caused this issue, but it does appear that the the problem also extends to `syslog`, `messages`, `user.log` and `daemon.log` (i.e. output from `apt/apt-get` and from package maintainer scripts is missing from these as well). I can see several `apt install/upgrade/purge` operations successfully logged in those files and then no more. I can tell there should be more entries logged, however, because my package calls `systemctl daemon-reload` and I can see `systemd[1]: Reloading` in the logs. From browsing `/var/log/dpkg.log`, it seems that none of those entries were every shown in `journald`, so that seems to still be fine. Logs from `/var/log/apt/term.log` are definitely missing from `journald`, but logs from `/var/log/auth.log` are still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be user error.

Logs from running `apt` directly from the terminal were *never* showing up in `journald`.

The `systemd` service in question is an auto-update service. The `apt` logging I was seeing in `journald` was occurring because the auto-update service was calling `apt-get` which, since it's a child process of the auto-update service, I guess logs to the same places as its parent (`syslog`, `daemon.log`, etc).